# Setting up zigbee network with X-CTU 6.3.2

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I'm trying to create Zigbee P2P using XB24C27WIT-004 modules with Digi USB explorers(CP2102). I am using 2 laptops and connected the XBee modules to each of them. I have added the modules to X-CTUs and changed the DL of one module as MY of another module and vice versa. Both are on same channel and same PAN ID. But i couldn't see the serially transmitted data from one console to another. The console window is as shown in the image. The commands are being seen when i'm trying to discover other radio.[The console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoGML.png). The function is set to ZIGBEE TH Reg for both modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured one as a coordinator (`ATCE=1`) and the other as a router (`ATCE=0`) so they can join to each other?  The Router can keep `ATDH` and `ATDL` as 0 to target the coordinator.  I'm not familiar with using the 16-bit network address for the destination, so I'd recommend setting `ATDH` to the router's `ATSH`, and `ATDL` to `ATSL`.

To confirm that the devices are joined to each other, their operating PAN ID (`ATOI` and `ATOP`) must match.  Once you see that, see if the router can send data to the coordinator, and then from the coordinator to the router.  You can use `ATNR` on the router to perform a Network Reset so it will try to re-join your coordinator.  You might need to set `ATNJ` to `0xFF` on the coordinator to allow joining.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for ur suggestion. We have tried ur configuration. The co-ordinator(CE=1) is receiving the data from router (CE=0) but co-ordinator is not being able to trasmit the data. We are monitoring the data in the consoles of the laptops. We have tried addressing as you suggested as well as given in [link](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/exploring-xbees-and-xctu). We have changed the DL of co-ordinator to FFFF to broadcast. Then both the xbees are being able to communicate. But we need p2p communication(DL of one xbee is MY of another xbee) and this doesn't work.

Comment: And @tomlogic what happens if we enable both of xbees as co-ordinators(CE=1) in the same PAN(same PAN ID).

Comment: If both are set as coordinators, they will establish two different networks.  You need to set `DH`/`DL` on the coordinator to the `SH`/`SL` of the router in order to unicast serial data to it.  `MY` is the 16-bit network address and I don't believe it will work in the `DL` setting.  Using an destination address of all zeros is a shortcut to indicate "network coordinator".

Comment: Is a co-ordinator necessary for a Zigbee PAN?? I thought zigbee networks are self healing and don't require a co-ordinator.

Comment: Yes, a coordinator is required to establish a ZigBee network.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee